# DetailController and routing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have made an angular app with this js script:

```
/**
 * Services
 **/
var app;

app = angular.module('example.api', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'controllers']);

app.factory('Post', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/posts/:id', {post: '@id'});
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/posts/:id', {templateUrl: "static/js/post_detail.html", controller: "PostListController"})
                  .when('/posts', {template: '<p>No link selected</p>', controller: "PostDetailController"})
                  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/posts'});
}]);

/**
 * Controllers
 **/
var controllers;

controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);

controllers.controller('PostListController', ['$scope', 'Post', function($scope, Post) {
    $scope.posts = Post.query();
}]);

controllers.controller('PostDetailController', ['$scope', 'Post', function($scope, Post) {
    $scope.post = Post.query();
}]);
```

and this html template:

```
<div class="row" ng-app="example.api">
    <div class="col-md-2" ng-controller="PostListController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
                {% verbatim %}
                    <a href="#/posts/{{ ::post.id }}">{{ ::post.id }}</a>
                {% endverbatim %}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10" ng-controller="PostDetailController">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is in `PostDetailController`. I don't know how to use `$resource` correctly. I've just tried `$scope.post = Post.query()` but I probably need to tell the resource to look at the variable `id` i think.

I've looked through the documentation but could still not figure it out.

Besides that I want to know if it's possible to avoid the website to first show my unrendered template before loading the posts in my `PostListController`. It's not really a problem but it's ugly that the site's flickering before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Post.get(id)` to get a specific entry.
2. Use a [resolver](http://sydney.ryanczak.org/?p=350). With that you tell angular to resolve some promises before redirecting to the new route.

EDIT:

You have to inject [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) to get the route's id. Now you can do this: `$scope.post = Post.get($routeParams.id);`

Comment: `$scope.post = Post.get(id);`?

Comment: So I guess it will be `controllers.controller('PostDetailController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Post', function($scope, $routeParams, Post) {
    $scope.post = Post.get($routeParams.id);
}]);` but it results in a resource error.